# Cordova mobile app by MS Visual Studio 2017

Tags: windows, installation, hybrid-mobile-app

I build a Cordova mobile app by MS Visual Studio 2017.
The Studio made a Release folder with following content:

```
\ilc folder
AppxManifest.xml
Project12.appxrecipe
resources.pri
SQLite3.pri
SQLite3.winmd
```

After the process of building the project Visual Studio install the app on my developer device automatically, but What should I do to install a mobile app on other Tablet with Windows 10 pro by
using only the files from Realese folder?